# Ionic app with node.js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework

**Hello !**

A bit of background, I'd want to create my first **android/iOS/webapp**. The idea is to create a **cross platform chat using** :

- [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) (and Javascript) for the app
- [Openshift](http://www.openshift.com) for the node.js server part

I was going to use Firebase to store the messages, but the free plan just works for 100~ simultaneous users, which ain't a lot ... So I was thinking about creating a **node.js** server using **MongoDB** to store everything. Users and messages.

The idea is that I'd get a better **server side control** on the data, and it seems to be nicer to me.

***But is it actually a good idea ?***
I'm not sure about the fact that it's **pertinent** to use a node.js server for that matter, I'm pretty new to those technologies (*I'm a Java/COBOL developer*) 
Thanks in advance !

**tl;dr : is storing and processing data for an iOS/Android/Webapp chat with a node.js server is a good idea ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea, in few hours you would have a working environment. With Ionic, being web technologies, you can use any library you want, probably the easiest one to use could be socket.io, is simple to use client side and simple server side. You would have rooms and everything already to exchange messages in realtime.

There are a ton of examples for using socket.io to make a chat so should be pretty easy to find infos. ( I made one myself )